# API Http get method is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, http, http-get

I have created simple API as below:

```java
public class TestController : ApiController { 
    [HttpGet, Route("ProductData")]
    public IHttpActionResult ProductData(int id) {
            try {
                List<Product> products = new List<Product>() {
                    new Product() { Name = "TestProduct", Id = "001", Quantity = "15-001" },
                    new Product() { Name = "TestProduct", Id = "002", Quantity = "15-002" },
                    new Product() { Name = "TestProduct", Id = "003", Quantity = "15-003" },
                    new Product() { Name = "TestProduct", Id = "004", Quantity = "15-004" },
                    new Product() { Name = "TestProduct", Id = "005", Quantity = "15-005" },
            };
                return Ok(products.Where(product => product.Id == id.ToString()).Select(product => product).FirstOrDefault());
            }
            catch {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I consume this service from console as below:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64672/");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage getData = httpClient.GetAsync("api/Test/ProductData", 135).Result;

if (getProductData.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var message = postMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Console.WriteLine(" Message from API : {0}", message.Replace(',', ' ').ToString());
}
```

But am not getting an output from API, instead IsSuccessStatusCode is coming as false, Please someone help me on this

When called from the browser, I get this error :

```
<Error> 
    <Message> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'localhost:64672/api/Test/ProductData?id=120'. 
    </Message> 
    <MessageDetail> No action was found on the controller 'IdsApp' that matches the name 'ProductData'. 
    </MessageDetail> 
</Error>
```

Comment: Does your route specify `api/` in the `WebApiConfig` file?

Comment: Don't use `.Result` to block asynchronous methods. Make your own method `async` and use `await`. As for what's wrong, what's the actual error? What is the status code? If you get a 404 it's probably because you use the wrong URL. There's no `api` in `Route("ProductData")`. Have you tried calling `Test/ProductData`? Have you tried typing the URL in the browser or POSTMAN?

Comment: @dunnel123 yes its mentioned

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I tried calling through console.

Comment: Using *what*? You can't make an HTTP call with CLI commands. You'd have to use `curl` at least. What did you try, what did you get? And what was the *error* in the first place? 404? That's a wrong URL. 401 or 403? Authentication/Authorization error. 500? The server threw

Comment: BTW `GetAsync` doesn't accept query parameters. The only overload that would accept an integer is [GetAsync(string,HttpCompletionOption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_String_System_Net_Http_HttpCompletionOption_).  What you did was call `ProductData` without any parametes, and specified 135 as an HttpCompletionOption.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - am trying through browser URI also and am getting      <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64672/api/Test/ProductData?id=120'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'IdsApp' that matches the name 'ProductData'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

Comment: @Prabakaran that's a 404 whose description is what you posted. Post that in the *question*, not the comments. The error tells you the wrong controller was called. What is `IdsApp`? Do you have that route configured somewhere? Did you copy route attributes?

Comment: @Prabakaran I can't stress this enough. Update the question and post the error there, along with any other relevant information. Otherwise the question can't be answered and will have to be closed - people can't *guess* what your route and code looks like

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - when i comment my [Route] attribute it works fine, can you please tell me why this is happeneing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It looks good, my error was in Route attribute, i corrected that and it worked, thanks for you valuable response

Comment: @dunnel123 -, my error was in Route attribute, i corrected that and it worked, thanks for you valuable response

Answer (score 3):

You can still use your routing but you have to do it a bit different.

```
HttpResponseMessage getData = httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("api/Test/ProductData?id={0}", 135)).Result;
```

Comment: @It looks good, my error was in Route attribute, i corrected that and it worked, thanks for you valuable response

Answer (score 2):

You should decorate the `int id` with a `[FromRoute]` attribute in your api controller action. So change the `int id` to `[FromRoute]int id`. Also change `Route("ProductData")` to `Route("ProductData/{id}")`. Finally, modify  `GetAsync()` uri like this:

```
var getData = httpClient.GetAsync($"api/Test/ProductData/{135}").Result;
```

Comment: Provide more detail about the response.

Comment: <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64672/api/Test/ProductData?id=120'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'IdsApp' that matches the name 'ProductData'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
 this is the error am getting when i call from browser

Comment: check the modified answer.

Comment: It looks good, my error was in Route attribute, i corrected that and it worked, thanks for you valuable response

Answer (score 2):

Its to do with how you've set your routing up as the others have said.

You need to decide whether you would like your URIs to look like

```
api/Test/ProductData?id={0}
```

Or

```
api/Test/ProductData/{0}
```

Personally I think it looks better as the second one as then you can chain other routes on top of it as so

```
api/Test/ProductData/{productId}/store/{storeID}
```

With that example pulling a product of productId from a specific store of storeId

End of the day its down to personal preference from how you want to structure you URIs

How to set up the second option is by changing the route attribute above the method as so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ProductData/{id}")]
public IActionResult ProductData(int id)
{
 .....Whatever code
}
```

Personally I don't like putting all attributes into the same square brackets but thats just my own style of writing code. Prefer to have the attributes separate I just find it easier to read

Comment: @It looks good, my error was in Route attribute, i corrected that and it worked, thanks for you valuable response